# Parse json string for specific value using JSONObject

Tags: java, json

In java, I am trying to parse values from this json..

```
[
{
    "2012-01-02": {
        "age": 3,
        "dob": "2010-01-03",
        "name": "jack"
    },
    "2012-01-03": {
        "age": 3,
        "dob": "2010-01-04",
        "name": "jill"
    },
    "2012-01-04": {
        "age": 3,
        "dob": "2010-01-05",
        "name": "john"
    },
    "2012-01-05": {
        "age": 3,
        "dob": "2010-01-06",
        "name": "miran"
    }
}
]
```

Using JSONObject, I was trying to get the value of just "age" and then add them up to do some data manipulation.

- I created a JSONObject
- Created an iterator and then stored them to a map
- This gets me the inner element like:

  ```
  {
      "age": 3,
      "dob": "2010-01-06",
      "name": "miran"
  }
  ```

After this, not sure how to extract just age from each element. Do i create another jsonobject and pass this new string, extract age out of it or is there a better way to do this? (I am sure there is one)

**UPDATE:**

This is what I currently have that gives me {"age":3,"dob":"2012-01-06","name":"miran"}

```
    JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();


        try {
            jsonobj = new JSONObject(pastweekVol);
            Iterator iter = jsonobj.keys();
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            while(iter.hasNext()){
                String jsonkey = (String)iter.next();
                String value = jsonobj.getString(jsonkey);
                logger.debug("first pass value is: {}", value);
                         } catch (JSONException je) {
                logger.debug("exception is: {}",je);
             }
```

I was thinking that since I am getting {"age":3,"dob":"2012-01-06","name":"miran"}, I would create another json object and pass in this string, which will give me value of "age". The problem here is that I get repetitive values. Of course, something very basic is missing here but I can't seem to figure that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the inner element as a `JSONObject` instance - say `person` - then you can directly access the age:

```
int age = person.getInt("age");
```

and do something with it:

```
sum += age;
```

Comment: @micha except that error checking with org.json is nothing less than a PITA. Just try it...

Comment: I get your idea... So, here is what I have so far:

Answer (score 0):

You might consider a library like Google's GSON (http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) if you want to be able to easily parse arbitrarily complex JSON strnigs into generic objects.

Comment: I am sorry but the requirement is that I have to use JSONObject

Answer (score 0):

Using org.json is probably not your best bet -- this API has many flaws. Using Jackson, you can easily extract `age` from each member value:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

JsonNode fullDocument = mapper.readTree(xxx); // xxx can be many things

// Not an object? Bail out
if (!fullDocument.isObject())
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("not an object");

// This will iterate through object values
for (JsonNode value: fullDocument)
    // do something with value.get("age")
    // in particular, you can test for .isIntegralNumber()
```